# Scatter plot point shape

Tags: scatter-plot, qliksense

Is it possible to change the scatter plot point from the usual circle to something else. And more specifically can this be linked to a Dimension?

I know I can change the colour but we are already using a Master Item colour, and need to and another dimension.

We are also using the marker size for a measure so we cant co-opt that either

We are using Qlik Sense (SaaS).

Answer (score 1):

From experience, no, you can't, I have ended up creating my own extension to create my own scatter plots to have donuts instead of dots using chart.js

Thanks,